# How to get ActionBar Title text color

Tags: android

I want to get ActionBar Title text style & color and set it for one TextView.

I did it by using the following:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:singleLine="true"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse"
        android:text="Title" />
```

Is there any better ways to get my current application theme's **titleTextStyle** ?

Comment: better way?? that is the best way.

Comment: But if app theme is changed to dark colors, I have to explicitly change here right. If a developer miss this at that time, it will come as a defect. If I am using titleTextStyle of the theme, I do not want to change it explicitly

Comment: how that your app change in theme?

Comment: If I change my app theme